# How to upload video via the VK api

Tags: api, upload, vk

I am new at `VK api`.
 I want to upload video via the VK API. I cannot get sample codes in my investigation in google.

Can anyone give me sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get http-url to upload video using [this](https://vk.com/dev/video.save) API method.

Then you should make a POST-request containing field with "video_file" which will contain your video file in binary mode. Then you should call [video.save](https://vk.com/dev/video.save)
 method to save changes and get video_id

Comment: step 1. I called the video.save as below;
https://api.vk.com/method/video.save?access_token=xxxx&link=http://yyyy.com/4144.mp4&description=testt

and get the response ;

{"response":{"upload_url":"xxxxxxxx","vid":171540312,"owner_id":xxxxxx,"name":"No name","description":"testt","access_key":"xxxxxxxxxx"}}

Comment: Then what I use the form to post the data as ;

<form method="POST" 
      action=upload_url">
     <input type="submit" value="SEND">
    <input type="file" name="video_file" size="45" />
</form>
but get the response ;"error_code":7,"error_msg":"no video found, check url"}

Comment: try to read what I wrote. First you need to get LINK where your will POST your VIDEO as BINARY DATA. It will be multipart-form-data-request. You do not allow to paste video-lin into "link"-parameted of video.save-method. Documentation is here https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=Uploading%20Videos. Change language in bottom-right corner of site

Comment: is it 
(https://api.vk.com/method/video.save?access_token=xxxx&link=http://yyyy.com/4144.mp4&description=testt) 

true link to get the video.save response in first step?

Comment: Too many pending edit request. But here we go: Get upload_url from first GET call to video.save request-url, next call POST to the upload_url. If you submit a link you don't need a video_file

Answer (score 1):

Using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library:

```
import requests

with open('upload_file_name', 'rb') as f:
    # use upload url you get from vk via 'video.save' call
    resp = requests.post(vk_upload_url, files={'video_file': f})

    # dumb response check
    if resp.json().get('size'):
        print('upload OK')
    else:
        print('shit happens!')
```

You can read about details in vk.api docs